# Should table be dropped when deleting obsolete Model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2, database-schema

I want to delete an old Model as part of keeping a Rails application's code clean. I would also like to ensure I have a backup of the data associated with that Model (it is persisted using PostgreSQL).

I'm not sure what best to do with the table. The two obvious options I can see are:

1. Backup the table using `pg_dump` and then drop the table with a migration
2. Leave the table in the schema, keeping all of the data in the database

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each? When would you pick one over the other?

**Extra info**

I'm actually clearing up a few different models, with tables ranging from around 100 rows to 50,000. Disk space is not currently issue for me, but it would be interesting to hear how table size affect this decision.

Comment: You'll have to be a bit less vague. Does the table store 5 rows or millions of rows? If you're not pressed for disk space then there is not much harm in leaving the table there.

Comment: I would drop the table if you don't need it, just for the sake of tiding up.  When you do the dump, just dump out the data for that table so it's easier to restore.

Comment: @Iceman Sorry - I was trying to keep the question specific to my situation, but it ended up a bit vague! Have updated the question now.

Comment: There isnt really a "right" answer here. Personally, I'd export the tables if I needed to keep the data forever. If I only needed to keep them temporarily until permanent deletion I just leave it in the DB.